# Windows batch file to extract few lines from a file and sum the values in a specific column

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, text-processing

I have a file file1.txt here and the content will be something like this

```
013A Not Visible            ???:? 09C:DB  2-Way Mir     N/Grp'd      RW       3     
013B Not Visible            ???:? 07A:DB  2-Way Mir     N/Grp'd      RW       3     
013C Not Visible            ???:? 08B:DB  2-Way Mir     N/Grp'd      RW       3          
0242 Not Visible            ???:? 10D:D3  RAID-5        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163     
0246 Not Visible            ???:? 10A:CB  RAID-5        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163     
024E Not Visible            ???:? 09D:D4  RAID-5        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163     
02A6 Not Visible            ???:? 06B:C8  RAID-5        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163         
09A8 Not Visible            ???:? 07C:D1  RAID-6        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163     
09AA Not Visible            ???:? 09D:C1  RAID-6        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163     
09AC Not Visible            ???:? 09A:C2  RAID-6        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163     
09B0 Not Visible            ???:? 08B:C0  RAID-6        N/Grp'd  (M) RW   43163
```

My task here is search for the word in the column showed above in bold letter and get the sum the digits in the last column for each category.

in above example I have 3 sets of words

1. 2-Way Mir
2. RAID-5
3. RAID-6

so i need sum the last columns. for `2-Way Mir`, sum is `3+3+3= 9`. 
How can I collect the same using batch file ?

Actual spacing:

Comment: This may not be a good fit for Windows batch processing because arithmentic is limited to signed 32 bit integers (max = 2147483647). Your sum may exceed the maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch math limitations make it impossible to create a reasonable pure batch solution if any sum exceeds 2147483647. There are complex routines that could be written to perform computations with large numbers in batch, but I don't consider them to be reasonable.

Assuming all sums are less than the max allowed, then the following solution works.

This would be so much easier if your "words" did not contain spaces. Normally, environment variables can contain spaces in the name. But the SET /A option does not support spaces in the variable name. So an extra set of mapping variables is required to map each unique "word" into a variable name that does not contain spaces. If the "word" never contains spaces, then the running sum can simply be stored in a variable that is directly derived from the "word".

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define input file
set "file=file1.txt"

:: Clear any existing $ variables and initialize unique "word" count
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('2^>nul set $') do set "%%V="
set "cnt=0"

:: Iteratively read each line in the file
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file%") do (

  %= Extract the correct "word" (%%N) from the line by position =%
  set "ln=%%A"
  for /f "delims=" %%N in ("!ln:~42,13!") do (

    %= If this is a new "word", then setup mapping =%
    if not defined $%%N (
      set /a cnt+=1        %= Increment unique "word" count     =%
      set "$%%N=!cnt!"     %= Map "word" to an "array" position =%
      set "name!cnt!=%%N"  %= Store "word" in name "array"      =%
    )

    %= Extract the value from line by position and add it to =%
    %= the appropriate array element by using the $word map  =%
    set /a "val!$%%N!+=!ln:~71!"
  )
)

:: Iterate the "arrays" and print results
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do echo !name%%N!  !val%%N!
```

Note: the code above uses an environment variable name convention to emulate arrays. Batch does not have true arrays.

Here are the results from the sample data in file1.txt:

```
2-Way Mir      9
RAID-5         172652
RAID-6         172652
```

Comment: I am getting below error while doing same operation on another file with more data "Missing operator.
Missing operator.
Missing operator."

Comment: I am seeing some space difference in the above question sample output and actual command ouput..

Comment: @user2536391 - Do any of the input lines have a different format? Are there any header lines? Do any lines contain `!` character? Do any lines contain additional data after the number column? Do any lines have missing data? If yes to any of the above, then the script must be modified to handle the variations. The posted output is literally a copy and paste from my screen after running the script.

Comment: sorry for the trouble.. there is some space difference between each column. actual output is uploaded here (second line in the below link) [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByX50099NyHyVmRfV3Ewd284UXM/edit)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByX50099NyHyVmRfV3Ewd284UXM/edit

Comment: @anoopcr - I cannot see any content at either link

Comment: @ dbenham : I have edited the question and added the actual content with correct spacing between the columns. please check..

Comment: @anoopcr - This site is for programming questions and answers; not a place to request people to write your code. All that was required was to change the substring parameters in the code. I've updated the answer for the new spacing and added extensive comments. Please make an effort to understand the code. You should be able to make any needed changes if the spacing should change again.

Answer (score 1):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
>awk "{a[$6]+=$NF} END {for (x in a) print x,a[x]}" file
RAID-5 172652
2-Way 9
RAID-6 172652
```

Please add `Mir`  to `2-Way`  for your convenience!
[Download here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (mir2 raid5 raid6) DO SET /a %%i=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file1.txt) DO CALL :process %%i
ECHO 2-Way Mir : %mir2%
ECHO RAID-5    : %raid5%
ECHO RAID-6    : %raid6%
GOTO :EOF
:process
SET "line=%*"
:loop
SET value=%2
IF DEFINED value shift&GOTO loop
SET line=%line:~38,9%
IF /i "%line%"=="2-way mir" SET /a mir2+=%1
IF /i "%line%"=="RAID-5   " SET /a raid5+=%1
IF /i "%line%"=="RAID-6   " SET /a raid6+=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

Should do the job for you. I'm assumming that the asterisks surrounding the keystring are a failed attempt to make those strings bold. I'm also assuming that the data is in fixed-column format. Actually, there could be an easier way if that is true:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (mir2 raid5 raid6) DO SET /a %%i=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file1.txt) DO CALL :process %%i
ECHO 2-Way Mir : %mir2%
ECHO RAID-5    : %raid5%
ECHO RAID-6    : %raid6%
GOTO :EOF
:process
SET "line=%*"
IF /i "%line:~38,9%"=="2-way mir" SET /a mir2+=%line:~70%
IF /i "%line:~38,9%"=="RAID-5   " SET /a raid5+=%line:~70%
IF /i "%line:~38,9%"=="RAID-6   " SET /a raid6+=%line:~70%
GOTO :EOF
```

which could be further simplified if required. Note that the length `9` must match in the `if` statements and the `/i` makes the `if` case-insensitive.

---

To extend matches - a little more complex, but automagically adjusts...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO SET "%%i="
SET maps="2-way mir" "RAID-5   "
SET maps=%maps% "RAID-6   "

SET strcnt=0
FOR %%i IN (%maps%) DO CALL :setup %%i
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file1.txt) DO CALL :process %%i
SET mapnbr=1
:ploop
CALL ECHO %%$_%mapnbr%%% : %%$%mapnbr%%%
SET /a mapnbr+=1
IF %mapnbr% leq %strcnt% GOTO ploop
GOTO :EOF
:process
SET "line=%*"
SET mapnbr=%strcnt%
:matchloop
CALL SET match=%%$_%mapnbr%%%
IF /i "%line:~38,9%"==%match% CALL SET /a $%mapnbr%+=%line:~70%&GOTO :eof
SET /a mapnbr-=1
IF %mapnbr% neq 0 GOTO matchloop
GOTO :EOF

:: Set $n=0 & $_n=string-to-match
:setup
SET /a strcnt+=1
SET /a $%strcnt%=0
SET    $_%strcnt%=%1
GOTO :eof
```

Essentially, variables `$n` contain the counts, `$_n` the strings to match in quotes. Just add more quoted 9-character strings into `maps` with space or comma-separators.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the script. yes asterisks due failed bold letter and data is n fixed column format. How can i echo the  sum to a common file something like this total RAID-5 is <sume value> ?  and also this is a sample and it may have more more vaules than 2-way,RAID-5,RAID-6.